# data of child window does not refresh while it is open mvvm in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, childwindow

I have a child window and there are a radgrid view and textboxes which show the radgridview items as I  select a row of gridview!and i'm using mvvm pattern.

when I open the child window it automatically show the data of last row as selected row in default but when I select another row although my bindings model are changed,the data in textboxes does not change while child is open!!!

Comment: have you checked your binding mode? it should be Twoway.

Comment: yes that is two way,and this is works on page but not on a child window!

Comment: Show us some code. It can be many things.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to bind like below mentioned code, it may help u.

```
 <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding  DataContext.FDE.EfileReturnedChecked,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:ChildWindow}, Mode=TwoWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```